# How do I use Jekyll to support GitHub pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

Ok, so I registered a subdomain with my DNS provider, I have made a repository on GitHub for the subdomain (CNAME and all) i'd like to make it a blog and apparently the best blog software which works with GitHub pages is Jekyll. I have installed Jekyll from chocolatey, which is supposed to be the best way to do it with Windows, but I still dont know how to get GitHub pages working with Jekyll.
Does anyone know?

Comment: You can read the doc at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

Comment: So... you do not know how to push your local Jekyll site to Github on the right branch... Is that your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to do is setup a directory structure in your `gh-pages` branch that Jekyll can understand. The rest happens pretty much automatically.

[Here](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/) is the guide I followed, and it focuses on getting the directory structure setup instead of installing stuff locally.

[Here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/) is another description of the directory structure you need to setup.

But the very basic structure you need is this:

- `_config.yml`: contains settings for your site
- `_layouts/default.html`: contains the layout html for your site
- `_posts/2016-06-15-hello-world.md`: Contains a post for your blog.

You can expand from there, but the basic answer is that you just need the correct directory structures, and everything else should happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To create a site on Github Pages you need to create a gh-pages branch using git and push that branch to Github. Your new site will be username.github.io/baseurl.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I know how to make a GitHub pages site. What I need to know is how to get Jekyll to use with GitHub pages.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Once you push the gh-pages branch to GitHub, your site should be there.

Comment: Do you know what jekyll is? Is has nothing to do with generating github pages.

Comment: I've even created [Jekyll themes](http://elotroalex.github.io/ed/). Trying to help here. Like I said, you need to push your Jekyll site to Github on a gh-pages branch.

Comment: Quick question, can you run your Jekyll site on a local server already?